# Обновление числа push-уведомлений в фоновом режиме

Tags: swift, xcode, push-уведомления

Каждый раз при отправке push-уведомлений я хочу добавлять к числу непрочитанных сообщений единицу.
При входе на страницу с уведомлениями счетчик обнуляется. Я хочу, чтобы при отправке сообщения в фоновом режиме выполнялся код

```
UserSettings.badge+=1 //добавляю к числу непрочитанных сообщений еще одно
UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = UserSettings.badge //меняю число на иконке приложения на главном экране
```

но у меня работает этот код только если приложение открыто. как мне это исправить?

Число сообщений сохраняю в том числе для того, чтобы менять иконку раздела с уведомлениями в зависимости от числа непрочитанных пуш-уведомлений

Comment: Можно подписаться на методы фреймворка PushKit в AppDelegate и там увеличивать счетчик.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, вы забыли добавить Background fetch в ваше приложение [image: Скриншот Background fetch]